# What is the closed-form for the number of permutations with a sum requirement for each permutation?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose the choices are {1, 2, ..., N}, the number of places to put a choice is M, and the values of each group (or permutation) must sum to N?

What is the general solution to the number of permutations for this?

For example, with N = 3 and M = 3, the permutations are {300, 210, 120, 021, 012, 030, 201, 102, 003, 111}.

For N = 2 and M = 3, the permutations are {200, 110, 020, 011, 101, 002}.

Also, what branch of mathematics would this fall into? It feels like it could be a linear algebra problem.

Comment: Those are not permutations, so do not call them that.

Comment: This is a standard balls-in-bins problem... you have $N$ indistinct balls you are placing into $M$ distinct bins.  Finding the number of possible outcomes is solved by a well-known technique called "[*stars-and-bars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))" and becomes $\binom{N+M-1}{M-1}$.  As for "*which branch of mathematics*" this is from?  Combinatorics, and is encountered in a first semester introductory course.

Comment: At first glance, one might suppose that the comment of @JMoravitz is *wrong*, because (for example) in the $N=3,M=3$ example, the ordered triplet $(3,0,0)$ can be permuted in 3 different ways, while the ordered triplet $(1,1,1)$ can only be permuted in 1 way.  In fact, JMoravitz' comment **is accurate**.  In addition to his cited Wikipedia article, I also recommend [this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/).